# How to hide/show specific Cell in Grid

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect

Im using renderer function as below and want to hide/show specific checkcolumn-cells depending on variable `record.data.hidden` in my gridview.

```
{
   xtype: 'checkcolumn',
   renderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store, view) {
       /*
       if (record.data.hidden === true) {
           // checkbox hidden
       } else {
           // checkbox shown
       }
       */
    },
    itemId: 'mycheck',
    bind: {
        text: '{warranty}'
    }
}
```

How do i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `metaData` passed to the renderer function to apply styling to the cell element, see the [documentation here](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/classic/Ext.grid.column.Column.html#cfg-renderer).

One easy way is to set the `display` CSS property depending on your criteria. This will be applied to the HTML `<td>` element created by Ext JS for the cell.

Try this:

```
{
   xtype: 'checkcolumn',
   renderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store, view) {
       if (record.data.hidden === true) {
           metaData.tdStyle = 'display: none;';
       } else {
           metaData.tdStyle = 'display: table-cell;';
       }
       return value;
    },
    itemId: 'mycheck',
    bind: {
        text: '{warranty}'
    }
}
```

(I am not sure about the right syntax, maybe you don't need the semicolon after `none` and `table-cell`, and maybe you have to use quotations somewhere. Try it.)

But you create a CSS style and use `tdCls` as well, and perhaps also `tdAttr` but I am not sure about the latest.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, thanks to Peter:

```
if (record.data.hidden === true) {
    metaData.tdStyle = 'display: none;';
    return (new Ext.grid.column.CheckColumn()).renderer(value);
} else {
    metaData.tdStyle = 'display: table-cell;';
    return (new Ext.grid.column.CheckColumn()).renderer(value);
}
```

Without the renderer() function, you will only see the "value" in raw without any checkbox.

Comment: Actually, I think it's enough to return the value which I forgot to add, I'll correct my answer please check.